# Parallelograms circumscribing the given $\|\ \|$-unit circle.

Tags: optimization, convex-geometry

Consider a norm $\|\ \|$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $\|\ \|$ is smooth,
strict convexity, i.e. $$\|v\|=\|w\|=1,\ v\neq w \Rightarrow \bigg\|
\frac{v+w}{2}\bigg\|<1$$ Define a function $$f: D\times D\rightarrow
\mathbb{R},\ f(v,w)=|{\rm det}\ [v\ w]|$$ where $D$ is $\|\ \|$-unit
ball.

**Problem :** When $f$ has a maximum at $(v_0,w_0)$, then convex hull of
$\{v_0\pm w_0, -v_0\pm w_0 \}$ contains $D$.

(Here I can not convince that we need the condition where $\partial
D$ is smooth.)

**Remark :** When $P$ is a parallelogram circumscribing $\|\ \|$-unit circle, then ${\rm area\ conv}\ (P)$ is minimum when $P$ is realized under the above way.

Comment: What do you mean by "parallelogram"? I assume you're not limiting yourself to a $2$-dimensional object, because you mention $P$ contains the unit sphere $S$. But then again, you do use the term "area", so I don't know what to think.

Comment: I add more explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "parallelogram" e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the metric $d(x,y)=|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|?$